# How to have Pyramid invoke_subrequest to go through view_config context routing for error handling

Tags: python, view, config, pyramid

We are using [`request.invoke_subrequest()`](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/subrequest.html) to run a view from Python code.

We would like the `subrequests` responses to go through the views defined for errors (`context routing`).

For example, if we define several error views like this one:

```
@view_config(context=requests.exceptions.HTTPError)
def response_error(context, request):
    if context.response.status_code == 412:
        return httpexceptions.HTTPPreconditionFailed()
    # [...]
```

How do you execute it when using `subrequests` for each kind of `context` without having to add an except close for each kind?

Ideally, we'd like to obtain something like that (e.g. imaginary `view_lookup()` function):

```
try:
    subresp = request.invoke_subrequest(subrequest)
except Exception as e:
    subresp = view_lookup(e)(subrequest)
```

Using `use_tweens=True` in `invoke_subrequest()` doesn't seem to execute the error views either.

Is there a way to explicitly call a `view lookup` so that we obtain the `subresponse` as if it would have gone through `view_config` errors handlers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is probably: `pyramid.view.render_view_to_response`

```
from pyramid.view import render_view_to_response

try:
    subresp = request.invoke_subrequest(subrequest)
except Exception as e:
    subresp = render_view_to_response(e, subrequest)
```